# JustGauge.js Insert Comma

Tags: javascript, justgage

I am struggling to insert a comma into my [JustGauge](http://justgage.com/) Chart.

So far I have the following code. most of it is working as expected;

```
window.onload = function() {

  var g1 = new JustGage({
    id: "g1",
    value: 24692,
    min: 0,
    max: 30009,
    title: 'Document Countdown',
    titlePosition: 'above',
    width: 800,
    height: 800,
    pointer: true,
    textRenderer: function(val) {
      return val.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
    },
    gaugeWidthScale: 1.2,
    noGradient: true,
    customSectors: [{
      color: '#32CD32',
      lo: 0,
      hi: 30009
    }]
  });
}
```

Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/johnny_s/xsgpp4ng/1/

The 'textRenderer' part of the above code adds a comma to the 'value', I'm not sure how to do the same with 'max'.

I need to add a comma to the 'max' value - so it's '30,009'. When I try to add it manually the chart won't load.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been a feature request posted as [request 193](https://github.com/toorshia/justgage/issues/193) and has been implemented as an extra property `maxTxt` in the update of [February 3, 2016](https://github.com/toorshia/justgage) and is part of release 1.2.7. Current version is 1.2.9.

Note that several features changed in version 1.2.9 compared to the version you used (1.2.2):

- the structure of the `customSectors`: it is no longer an array. The array part is now moved into a subproperty `ranges`
- Support for `title` has been removed, as this really does not belong to the "core business" of the widget; one can better control the position and style of such a title in the surrounding HTML/CSS.
- There is a bug related to the `noGradient` setting: [issue 270](https://github.com/toorshia/justgage/issues/270). The suggested fix has not been included in the latest release. Instead of tampering with the library yourself, I would suggest working around that issue by adding a `customSectors.length` property with a positive value.

I have included these changes also in the [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ppke8tqp/1/) which uses version 1.2.9:

```
var g1 = new JustGage({
      id: "g1", 
      value: 24692,
      min: 0,
      max: 30009,
      maxTxt: "30,009", // <------ add this
      // remove title attributes -- no longer supported
      //title: 'Document Countdown',
      //titlePosition: 'above',
      width: 800,
      height: 400, // <--- reduced to allow title to be closer to gauge
      pointer: true,
      textRenderer: function(val) {
            return val.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
      },
      gaugeWidthScale: 1.2,
      pointerOptions: {
        toplength: -15,
        bottomlength: 10,
        bottomwidth: 12,
        color: '#8e8e93',
        stroke: '#ffffff',
        stroke_width: 3,
        stroke_linecap: 'round'
      },
      noGradient: true,
      customSectors: { // <--- no longer an array...
        ranges: [{ // <--- ... which has moved to this property
          color: '#32CD32',
          lo : 0,
          hi : 30009
        }],
        length: 1 // fixes a bug
      }
});
```

The HTML should contain the title. Something like this:

```
<div style="display: inline-block">
  <h2 style="text-align:center;">Document Countdown</h2>
  <div id="g1"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way of doing it is add `formatNumber: true` when you initialize. It will format min max and value. You can also get rid of the `textRenderer` field.

I updated your [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xsgpp4ng/2)

```
window.onload = function(){
         var g1 = new JustGage({
          id: "g1", 
          value: 24692, /* <-- just change this to your current value */
          min: 0,
          max: 30009, /* start amount */
          title: 'Document Countdown',
          titlePosition: 'above',
          width: 800,
          height: 800,
          pointer: true,
          formatNumber: true,
          gaugeWidthScale: 1.2,
            pointerOptions: {
            toplength: -15,
            bottomlength: 10,
            bottomwidth: 12,
            color: '#8e8e93',
            stroke: '#ffffff',
            stroke_width: 3,
            stroke_linecap: 'round'
          },
          noGradient: true,
          customSectors: [{
            color: '#32CD32',
            lo: 0,
            hi: 30009
          }]
        });
}
```